# Laravel Auth::user() get attributes

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

when i `dump( Auth::user());` that show me

```
User {#220 ▼

  #attributes: array:10 [▼
    "id" => "8"
    "name" => "Vitaliy"
    "email" => "dsadsa@i.ua"
    "password" => "=)"
    "remember_token" => null
    "created_at" => "2017-10-19 13:11:21"
    "updated_at" => "2017-10-19 13:11:21"
    "phone" => "412412412"
    "city" => "Dnipro"
    "district" => "Leneinskiy"
  ]
  #original: array:10 [▶]
 ....
}
```

In protected property we saw the info from user table
How can i get `#attributes`?
Or say me please how i can take all info about logged User.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Auth::user()->name`

`Auth::user()->email`

etc...

Answer (score 3):

```
Auth::User()->getAttributes();
```

This will get all the attributes of the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

#### simply you can use

```
$user = (Auth::User())->toArray();
```

#### or

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection
$user = (new Collection(Auth::User()))->toArray();
```